# Iphone Icon Changed

Tags: iphone

Hi When i start to develop my application , I used iPhone version 2.0.... Now i have update Iphone version 3.0..

My simulator works fine both in iphone 2.0 as well as iphone 3.0..

But When i run my application in 2.0 all icons in the iphone should be correct . But when i run this in 3.0 my other applications icons are changed....
(Example my safari icon should be placed to itunes and itunes icon to settings likewise all icons changed)

I dont know why?

Can anyone help me?

THanks in advance.......

Answer (score 1):

Apple updated the icons for most, if not all, of the system apps between 2.0 and 3.0. What you're seeing is expected behavior.